# View IE multiple tabs in tile view

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, tabs, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Would anybody know how to view multiple tabs in IE11 using the old "tile view"?

(I wonder whether they have disabled this altogether & replaced it with the "show previews for individual tabs in the taskbar". If they have: boooo!).

We have to navigate through 25+ tabbed browsers and trying to do this by looking at the tabs (too small!) or the taskbar (not very clear) is getting confusing.

Could somebody suggest how to open up the tabs in the old "tile view" or "cascade view"

We are running Windows 10, IE10, thanks

Comment: You ask about IE11 then mention IE10, you also have tagged this as Win8 but talk about Win10 exclusively. Can you clarify the browser and OS you are using? As far as I know IE10 is not available at all on Win10.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the exact need is but all the tabs` configuration are here.
[image]

Comment: Thanks I had a dig around that, but no luck.
We need to navigate between 25+ open tabs.
And it is difficult to do so using the tabs (which are tiny) or the the taskbar previews.
Something like the old "tile view" or "cascade view" would be perfect.
Hope somebody may be able to help.......
Best
Neil